# Erro ao popular grafico do google charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-charts, header

Estou me deparando com o seguinte erro:

> VM3611:231 Uncaught Error: Unknown header type: 6

Código:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "/client/ajax",
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false
    }).responseJSON;

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Name' , 'Tickets']
    ]);

    for(var i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){
        var array = [jsonData[i].Name , jsonData[i].Tickets]
        data = (google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            array
        ]));
    }
    var chart = new google.visualization.L

ineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data);
```

Nunca usei o charts, gostaria de saber se estou fazendo certo? E o motivo do erro? Obrigado a comunidade!

Comment: Qual o tipo de [chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) vc quer fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na maneira que consegui visualizar os dados, chamei `arrayToDataTable()` apenas uma vez. Veja o código abaixo.

Quanto a erros, encontrei só um erro de sintaxe. No código postado, falta o } no final da função. Acredito que o código não rodava porque arrayToDataTable() estava sendo chamada repetidamente para cada objeto (array) do JSON, e na verdade ele precisa da linha de "header".

Os dados JSON foram trocados por estáticos. Espero que te ajude!

```js
   google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   function drawChart() {
     var jsonData = [
       { "Name": "Joe", "Tickets": 300 },
       { "Name": "Karl", "Tickets": 200 },
       { "Name": "Tina", "Tickets": 900 },
     ];
       
     var dataArray = [
       ['Name' , 'Tickets'],
     ];

     for(var i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){
       var row = [jsonData[i].Name , jsonData[i].Tickets];
       dataArray.push(row);
     }

     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);

     var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
     chart.draw(data);
   }
```

```css
#chart_div {
       height: 100%;
   }
```

```html
<div id="chart_div">
  </div>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado

Comment: De nada! :) :) :)